# PowerShell Import CSV to add Active Directory Security Groups

Tags: csv, powershell

I have a CSV from a client with a few columns in it. A column for Email, SamAccountName, SecurityGroups.

In the Security Group column, each Security Group is separated by a ','
Each row would look like below

```
User1 User1@email.com SecurityGroup1, SecurityGroup2, SecurityGroup3
User2 User2@email.com SecurityGroup1, SecurityGroup2, SecurityGroup3
User3 User3@email.com SecurityGroup13, SecurityGroup5, SecurityGroup6
```

A list of users in different Security groups, how do I go about reading the CSV and only adding the Security Groups each user needs.

Below is what I have so far, when I run it in WhatIf mode it adds all the security groups to one user.

```
Clear
$ADGroup = $null
$i = 0
$ADGroup  = import-csv 'File.csv'
$sADGroup = $ADGroup.'Groups required'
Import-CSV "TestUsers.csv" | % {  
    $SAM = $_.SamAccountName
    $ADUser = Get-Aduser -filter {SamAccountName -eq $SAM} -Properties * | Select SamAccountName, MemberOf
    Write-Host 'SamAccountName :' $_.SamAccountName ' - ADUser - '  $SAM
    $sADGroup | ForEach-Object{
            Write-HOst $ADGroup.ADgroup[$i]
            Add-ADGroupMember $sADGroup.split(",")[$i] -Members $ADUser.SamAccountName -WhatIf
            $i += 1
            }
    }
```

Comment: I assume `testusers.csv` contains the name,groups and emails column so whats in the `file.csv`.  Are you trying to add user1 to groups 1,2,3 & user3 to 13,5,6?

Comment: Yep Testuser.csv has columns under them names. Yes add user 1 to groups1,2,3.

Comment: Ok I have figure it out, help with a work mate - Import-Csv 'testusers.csv' | 
    ForEach-Object {
           add-content $LogFile "Adding User to Group - $($_.Name)"
           Try{
           Add-ADPrincipalGroupMembership -identity $_.'SamAccountName' -memberof ($_.'Groups' -split', ')
            }
           Catch {
            Add-content $LogFile "Error adding user to group - $($_.Name)"
           }
           
     }

Answer (score 0):

Here is the final script, using AD-ADPrincipalGroupMembership was the find, instead of using Add-ADGroupMember

```
Import-Csv 'testusers.csv' | 
    ForEach-Object {
           add-content $LogFile "Adding User to Group - $($_.Name)"
           Try{
           Add-ADPrincipalGroupMembership -identity $_.'SamAccountName' -memberof ($_.'Groups' -split', ')
            }
           Catch {
            Add-content $LogFile "Error adding user to group - $($_.Name)"
           }

     }
```

Comment: Nice. If you want to catch non-terminating exceptions you need to add the parameter `ErrorAction` so i would write this line as so:   `Add-ADPrincipalGroupMembership -identity $_.SamAccountName -memberof ($_.Groups.tostring().trim().split(',').trim() ) -ErrorAction Stop`..........  the `trim()` will trim out any leading or trailing whitespaces which can be a possibility when the data comes from a csv file.

Comment: Ah thank you for the update, I will give it a go. Thanks all

Comment: When I have one security group in there it works, then when I have more than one it doesn't.

Comment: assuming your first row contains 2 groups separated by commas. what do you get when you type this:     `Import-Csv 'testusers.csv' | select -First 1 | % { $_.Groups.trim().split(',').trim()}`

Comment: I get both groups, one under each other.
Group1
Group2

Comment: Update- found an issue. Not with the script, but the way the Security Groups was created. Not all the Security Groups are called the same as thier SamAccountName for example: name =  'Group 1 - Test' SamAccountName = 'Group1'. So the 2nd group I was added didnt have the correct SamAccountName even though the Name which is displayed in AD was correct.

Comment: Yes this gets more complicated with exchange but anyways glad you figured it out.